# using { ref } to retrieve a div coordinates

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, ref

I'm working in VUeJS on a project of chat and I'd like to create a tooltip appearing on top of the username I hover over with my mouse pointer.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <Tooltip
        :user="user"
        :selectedUser="tooltipUser"
        :left="left"
        :top="top"
        v-if="tooltipVisible"
    />
    <div class="socialUsers" v-show="activeTab === 'users'">
        <div class="user" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
            <img class="avatar" :src="getUserAvatarUrl(user.avatar)" :alt="user.username" ref="chatTooltip" @click="displayTooltip(user)">
            <span class="username" :style="{ color: user.usernameColor }">{{ user.username }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import User from '@/models/user.model'
import Tooltip from '@/components/profile.tooltip.vue'

defineProps<{
    activeTab: string
    users: User[]
    user: User | null
}>()

const tooltipVisible = ref(false)
const tooltipUser = ref<User | null>(null)
const user = ref(tooltipUser)
const left = ref(0)
const top = ref(0)

const displayTooltip = (user: User): void => {
    tooltipUser.value = user
    tooltipVisible.value = !tooltipVisible.value
    const chatTooltip = this.$refs.chatTooltip
    if (chatTooltip) {
        const rect = chatTooltip.getBoundingClientRect()
        left.value = rect.x
        top.value = rect.y
    }
}

const getUserAvatarUrl = (filename: string): string => {
    return `http://${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST}:${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_PORT}/users/avatar/${filename}`
}
</script>
```

I'd like to pass to the Tooltip component the variables 'left' and 'top' that I'd like to retrieve with `this.$refs.chatTooltip`

Would it be possible ? Are there better solutions ?

Thanx a lot for your help,

Fab

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get your question properly. But I think it is about finding the ref of the img being clicked on.

Here your ref chatTooltip is an array (as in [Refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)). You should be able to get the proper ref using the index of the user being clicked on.

I'm not really sure about my TS code, but it should be like that.

```html
<div class="user" v-for="(user,i) in users" :key="user.id">
    <img class="avatar" :src="getUserAvatarUrl(user.avatar)" :alt="user.username" ref="chatTooltips" @click="displayTooltip(user,i)">
    <span class="username" :style="{ color: user.usernameColor }">{{ user.username }}</span>
</div>
```

```
const tooltipVisible = ref(false)
const tooltipUser = ref<User | null>(null)
const user = ref(tooltipUser)
const left = ref(0)
const top = ref(0)
const chatTooltips = ref([])

const displayTooltip = (user: User, i: number): void => {
    tooltipUser.value = user
    tooltipVisible.value = !tooltipVisible.value
    const chatTooltip = chatTooltips.value[i]
    if (chatTooltip) {
        const rect = chatTooltip.getBoundingClientRect()
        left.value = rect.x
        top.value = rect.y
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is a strip-down version of your code, that I'm able to execute.
It should be a good skeleton to re-build your component.

```js
<template>
    <div class="socialUsers">
        <div class="user" v-for="(user, i) in users" :key="user.id">
            <img class="avatar" :alt="user.username" ref="chatTooltips" @click="displayTooltip(user, i)">
            <span class="username" :style="{ color: user.usernameColor }">{{ user.username }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const tooltipVisible = ref(false)
const left = ref(0)
const top = ref(0)
const chatTooltips = ref([])

const users = [
    { username: 'joe', usernameColor: '#ff0000', id: 0 },
    { username: 'jane', usernameColor: '#00ff00', id: 1 },
]

const displayTooltip = (_user: Object, i: number): void => {
    tooltipVisible.value = !tooltipVisible.value
    const chatTooltip = chatTooltips
    if (chatTooltip) {
        console.log(chatTooltip)
        const rect = chatTooltips.value[i].getBoundingClientRect()
        left.value = rect.x
        top.value = rect.y
         
        console.log(rect)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: As chatTooltip is a ref, you should use chatTooltip.value. Let me know.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I'll try your solution. My issue is that `this.$refs.chatTooltip` in my code is undefined

Comment: Are you sure about this `this.$refs` usage ? For exemple in vuejs3 javascript, refs should be declared as a variable. I can edit the code to reflect that.

Comment: this is the [error](https://i.imgur.com/rwpjp5D.png) the code gives me after your suggestions.

Comment: That's right. There is no `this` using composition api. You can see my previous comment. I just edited my answer. You can also see in the doc, how a template ref is declared https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for

Comment: well, I'm not sure anymore... and I suppose the onMounted() function should help too, as in the first example in the [link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) you sent

Comment: Not really. onMounted is used in the exemple to console.log the template refs, once the DOM is updated (and therefor the refs are set). But in your case, as your function is executed onclick, you know the component is already mounted. Did you try my updated answer ? (with `const chatTooltip = ref([])` and `const chatTooltip = chatTooltip.value[i]`)

Comment: `property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'never'`

Comment: My bad. The ref array should be named chatTooltips (with an s, otherwise it collide with the local variable), both time in the ts and in the html part. I edited the code (hopefully for the last time).

Comment: no, I corrected that, don't worry. The problem comes from the `getBoundingClientRect`, which can't be attributed to a [] object...